# Live Sass Compiler Not Showing the Messages in the Output Window

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I use the "[Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass&ssr=false#overview)" extension in VS Code.

The problem is that when I want to print out a message using the [`@warn`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/warn) or the [`@debug`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/debug) at-rule in an SCSS file and hit the "Watch Sass" button, it successfully generates the CSS output, but it doesn't show the messages in the output window.

[image]

The extension is up-to-date, BTW. I also haven't found any related settings. What should I do?

Comment: Did you work anything out? I'm also having this problem.

Comment: @Josh Unfortunately, no. I had to install the Sass transpiler myself and transpile my Sass files to CSS via the terminal by typing commands manually. That being said, I'm satisfied this way, it's relatively easy to do.

Comment: @aradalvand can you explain/elaborate on the process?

Comment: @RockyBarua You need to install the Sass command-line tools: https://sass-lang.com/install